# Ошибка при подключении к БД mysql с использованием родного коннектора для .net

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

```
Authentication to host '192.168.0.14' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream has failed
```

Ошибка возникает в момент открытия соединения. 
Причем через *Workbench* я спокойно подключаюсь к *БД* с этим же логином и паролем.

Вот фрагмент кода, где возникает данная ошибка:

```
conStrBilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBilder();
conStrBilder.Server = "192.168.0.14";
conStrBilder.Database = "login";
conStrBilder.UserID = "root";
conStrBilder.Password = "root";
DataTable dt = null;
var con = new MySqlConnection(conStrBilder.ConnectionString);
var command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
try
{
    //здесь вываливается исключение
    con.Open()
    var dr = command.ExecuteReader();
    If(dr.HasRows)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
    }
}
catch(Exceprion ex)
{
    errorString = ex.Message;
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Версия *mysql* на сервере(RHEL): *14.4 Distrib 5.7.11*

Версия коннектора для .net: 6.9.8 (скачал с официального сайта). Также попробовал версию 7.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена.

Заработало с вот этим коннектором MySQL Connector NET 6.8.3

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте отключить Pooling соединений (добавить "Pooling=False;" в ConnectionString)
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76597

Comment: Пробовал - не помогло. Перечитал все репорты на официальном сайте - видел полно заявок с подобной проблемой, но так и не увидел там решения(((